# ElasticSearch 5: Search nested field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have the following document, and it got indexed into ElasticSearch 5.5

```
{
    "dept_id": "DP123",
    "related_depts": [
        {
            "id": "DP222",
            "roles": [
                {
                    "status": null,
                    "persons": [
                        {
                            "id": "P123",
                            "roles": [
                                {
                                    "status": null
                                }
                            ]
                        },

                        {
                            "id": "P124",
                            "roles": [
                                {
                                    "status": null
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Right now, I want to search for all the docs that has **persons id=P123**
I used the following command to search.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
     "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "related_depts.roles.persons",
            "query" : {
                "match" : {
                    "id": "P123"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

and I'm getting the follwing error.

```
failed to find nested object under path [related_depts.roles.persons]
```

Answer (score -1):

All of your objects are inside of arrays.
As such, you'll need to search the first index of each:

```
related_depts[0].roles[0].persons[0]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You didn't mention that you had tried that; there's no need for the hostility.

Comment: your path clause is wrong, you should insert there only the name of the nested object not your ramification https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html